# How to setup nginx location in site configuration to avoid "rewrite or internal redirection cycle" error

Tags: linux, nginx

I have following lines in my site.conf for nginx

```
Server {

  # Some other stuff ...

  location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args $uri/=404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /var/www;
        internal;
    }

    location ^~ /app.css {
        alias /var/www/public/css/app.css;
        access_log off;
    }
  }
}
```

But this is causing error which states `rewrite cycle for 404 page`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your alias end in app.css? Shouldn't it be a folder not a file?

Comment: Tim: The app.css location is perfectly OK. I am suspecting that the server is not able to figure out 404 and so going in the loop. After I removed the last argument to  `try_files ...`  everything worked just fine.

Comment: The `try_files` looks odd to me, unless you have some cases where `index.php` doesn't exist...